# Как получить данные из Service в класс

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-service

Есть класс который получает данные для фрагмента

```
package tanat.androidtesttask.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import tanat.androidtesttask.activity.MainActivity;

public class LoadAllData {

    private final Context context;

    public LoadAllData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ArrayList loadDemoData (Context context, int numberOfDownloads){
        String jsonStr = "";

        if (numberOfDownloads == 0) {
            jsonStr = loadLocalData(context);
            //делаем проверку на наличие локальной базы
            if (jsonStr == null || jsonStr.equals("")) {
                jsonStr = loadInetData();
            }
        } else {
            jsonStr = loadInetData();
        }

        ArrayList demoData = new JSONParsing().examineJSONDemoString(jsonStr);
        return demoData;
    }

    public String loadLocalData (Context context) {
        LoadLocalData loadLocalData;
        loadLocalData = new LoadLocalData(context);
        return loadLocalData.readFile();
    }

    public void pullLocalData (Context context, String localJsonStr) {
        LoadLocalData loadLocalData;
        loadLocalData = new LoadLocalData(context);
        loadLocalData.writeFile(localJsonStr);
    }

    public String loadInetData (){
        return MainActivity.loadData();
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том что загрузка данных методом loadInetData через MainActivity.loadData() реализована не правильно (я бы даже сказал быдлокод).
Этот метод должен получать данные из службы которая создается сразу после старта приложения и в потоке загружает данные из сети, а фрагмент во время загрузки данных должен крутить прогрес диалог. 
Но я не могу это реализовать уже вторые сутки.

Код фрагмента:
package tanat.androidtesttask.fragments;

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.Unbinder;

import tanat.androidtesttask.activity.InfoRoutActivity;
import tanat.androidtesttask.activity.MainActivity;
import tanat.androidtesttask.R;
import tanat.androidtesttask.service.ConectService;
import tanat.androidtesttask.service.TestService;
import tanat.androidtesttask.utils.LoadAllData;

public class ListFragment extends android.app.ListFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    // unbilder для роботы butterknife с фрагментом

    private View rootView;
    private DialogFragment dialogFragment;

    @BindView(R.id.refresh) SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.standart_layout) LinearLayout contentLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.error_layout) LinearLayout errorLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.errorTextView) TextView errorTextView;

    //кнопка для обновления в случае ошибки
    @OnClick(R.id.refreshButton)
    void onRefreshClick() {
        onRefresh();
    }

    //подключаем мой фрагмент
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

        dialogFragment = new AlterDialog();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    private ArrayList data = null;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        onRefresh();
    }

    //вешаем слушатель на нажатие итема фрагмента
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        //передаем позицию елемента в второе активити
        //создаем интент
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListFragment.this.getContext(), InfoRoutActivity.class);
        //записываем в него ключ и позицию
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        //передаем
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    int numberOfDownloads = 0;

    //свайп вниз для обновления
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // начинаем показывать прогресс
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        // вызываем загрузку данных 
        LoadAllData loadAllData = new LoadAllData(getActivity());
        data = loadAllData.loadDemoData(getActivity(), numberOfDownloads);

        numberOfDownloads++;

        if(data.size() > 0){
            // данные для списка есть
            // теперь проверим правильно ли была выполнена сетевая операция
            if(data.get(0).toString().equals("false")){
                // сетевая операция не прошла
                // меняем видимость layout так, что б не было видно рабочего layout и был виден
                // layout ошибки и вводим текст ошибки в textView
                contentLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                errorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errorTextView.setText(data.get(1).toString());
            } else {
                //если сетевая операция прошла успешно
                errorLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                contentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // создаем список
                createdList();
            }
        } else {
            //если данных списка нету
            errorLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            contentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // создаем список (ListFragment автоматически выведет заданое сообщение)
            createdList();
        }

        // прячем прогресс
        swipeRefreshLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                //либо используем наш класс
        //        dialogFragment.dismiss();
            }
        }, 300);
    }

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // метод создание списка
    public void createdList(){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Код сервиса:

```
package tanat.androidtesttask.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class ConectService extends Service {

    final String LOG_TAG = "MyLog";
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    private static String inetJsonStr = "";

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
        someTask();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public void someTask() {
        GetTask getTask = new GetTask();
        getTask.execute();
        try {
            inetJsonStr = getTask.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getInetJsonStr() {
        if (inetJsonStr.equals("")){

            return null;
        } else {
            return inetJsonStr;
        }
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public ConectService getService() {
            return ConectService.this;
        }
    }

    private class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strJson = "";
            InputStream inputStream;

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса и переделываем в строку
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://projects.gmoby.org/web/index.php/api/trips?from_date=2016-01-01&to_date=2018-03-01");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "strJson not null");
                strJson = buffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                strJson = e.getMessage();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson);
            }

            return strJson;
        }
    }
}
```

Задача явно не из простых и очень надеюсь что здесь найдутся желающие поломать себе голову над этим (я свою уже сломал).
Ссылка на [git](https://github.com/Pahan-Titan/AndroidTestTask)
Зарание спасибо.

Comment: Первое замечание: строка `inetJsonStr = getTask.get();` в сервисе тормозит главный поток и может вызвать ANR. Нужно перенести в `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`. Второе зачем вообще сервис - просто загрузить одну строку? По-моему это излишество, достаточно асинка или лодыря.

Comment: За первое замечание спасибо, а по поводу второго, такая стоит задача.

Comment: Сейчас стараются избегать asynctask . Без него обойтись никак?

Comment: Можете лишние убрать? Тяжело читать ваш код

Comment: без asynctask  можно
главное что б служба загружала данные
а фрагмент крутил прогрес а после завершения загрузки данных службой, принимал и выводил их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный способ решения такой проблемы это т.н. [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html?hl=ru)

Суть которой с точки зрения прогера состоит в неких манипуляциях при запуске `Service` с тем, чтобы в оконцове получить ссылку на экземпляр запущенного сервиса, который далее можно использовать как обычный Java объект, обращаясь к нему за некими данными:

```
ConectService myConnectService;
//бла-бла, связываем и проч.
//***************
myData=myConnectService.getSomeData();  //получаем данные из сервиса
```

У вас код связывания в самом сервисе уже написан, надо только реализовать вызов биндинга во фрагменте или `Activity` (читайте в документации - ссылка выше)

Comment: Направление Вы поняли, НО вызвать сервис нужно из отдельного класса (который не является активити). К сожалению что то вроде
context.bindService(intent, sConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
а за тем 
result = conectService.getInetJsonStr(); не работает.
Выдает:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String tanat.androidtesttask.service.ConectService.getInetJsonStr()' on a null object reference

Comment: Потому что вы неправильно коннектите, поэтому ссылка на `conectService` у вас `null` - вкурите мануал по ссылке в ответе, там все очень подробно расписано как биндить сервис.

Comment: Я этот мануал уже третьи сутки курю)
Всё равно не вижу, ткните носом пожалуйста
Вот в этом [классе](https://github.com/Pahan-Titan/AndroidTestTask/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tanat/androidtesttask/utils/LoadAllData.java) метод setsConnection.
Почти такой же код бинда в MainActiviti работает на ура.

Comment: Уберите  в строке 87 `bound = true` - признак `bound` выставляется только после отработки колбэка бинда... Бинд происходит не мгновенно, а асинхронно, так что вызов `getInetJsonStr()` нельзя производить сразу же... В общем у вас код не *event driven*